# BufferedReader inside TreeMap

Tags: java, bufferedreader, treemap

```
private static TreeMap<Integer, BufferedReader> firstMap = new TreeMap<Integer, BufferedReader>();
.
.
.
.
//fileNames is a list of file names in a directory...

for(int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++){
    if(!fileNames[i].startsWith(".")){
    String fileName = dirName + "/" + fileNames[i];
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        firstMap.put(i, br);
    }
}
```

When accessed later like this:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++){
            BufferedReader tempBr = firstMap.get(i);
            String line = tempBr.readLine();
}
```

It gives NullPointerException...

How can I make it work???

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, understand the problem. If every file in your directory started with a period, your TreeMap would be empty. But what happens if you firstMap.get(i) and firstMap does not contain the key i?

The [documentation for Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) (an interface that TreeMap implements) tells you this:

> V get(Object key):
>   Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.

Thus, if the key is not found in your TreeMap, tempBr will be null. Then, when you call tempBr.readLine(), you get a NullPointerException because null doesn't have a readLine() method or any other method.

```
BufferedReader tempBr = firstMap.get(i);
String line = tempBr.readLine();
```

Solution:
Though you could do this with a Map, ArrayList or LinkedList seem to be the more natural choices. This looks like homework, so I'm not giving you exact code to fix your problem. Here's an example that illustrates your problem and its solution.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class MyClass {
static final String[] fileNames = {"a", ".b", "c", ".d", "e", ".f"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    incorrect();
    corrected();
    improved();
}

public static void incorrect() {
    Map<Integer, String> myMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
        if (!fileNames[i].startsWith(".")) {
            myMap.put(i, fileNames[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(myMap);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(myMap.get(i));
    }
}

public static void corrected() {
    Map<Integer, String> myMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
        if (!fileNames[i].startsWith(".")) {
            myMap.put(i, fileNames[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(myMap);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
        if (myMap.containsKey(i)) {
            System.out.println(myMap.get(i)); 
        }
    }
}

public static void improved() {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String fileName : fileNames) {
        if (!fileName.startsWith(".")) {
            myList.add(fileName);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(myList);

    for (String fileName : myList) {
        System.out.println(fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... later I solved this problem with another approach by creating an array of my custom object that returns a BufferedReader.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are only adding some integers and `BufferedReaders` in the `TreeMap` in this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++){
    if(!fileNames[i].startsWith(".")){
        String fileName = dirName + "/" + fileNames[i];
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        firstMap.put(i, br);
    }
}
```

Specifically only those for which the condition is `true`.

Then later you are accessing all possible `i` values, and some might not exist in the `TreeMap`. The `get` method will in this case return `null`.

You will need to also check the condition in the second loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
   if(!fileNames[i].startsWith(".")){
        BufferedReader tempBr = firstMap.get(i);
        String line = tempBr.readLine();
   }
}
```